# Flickering CSS3 Animation On Load

Tags: css, animation

I see flickering my #content before animation is started. It works if I add opacity:0 to #content. But then there is no support for old browser. Any other solution?

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9vafv3sn/

```
#content {
    -webkit-animation: anime1 .6s .1s ease-in forwards;
    background-color: #aaa;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes anime1 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        top: -100px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        top: 0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Animations depend, as you know, on the web client you're using. Which is?

Comment: If you want to support old browsers you should use jquery or other easy animation framework.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware do you see the webkit vendor prefix? :)

Comment: @Brunis: Yes, I can read. To copy a tiny part of WikiP: "New web browsers have been built around WebKit such as the S60 browser[38] on Symbian mobile phones, BlackBerry Browser (ver 6.0+), Midori, Chrome browser, the Android Web browser, and the browser used in PlayStation 3 system software from version 4.10. KDE's Rekonq web browser and Plasma Workspaces also use it as the native web rendering engine.". So, it seems nice to know what's used.

Comment: Well, I look for a solution like: Modernizr .no-support {opacity:1;}

Comment: @KIKOSoftware if you could explain why you need to know what GUI wraps the webkit engine instead of just rambling and quoting that would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at it in Chrome for Windows, and I see what you mean. You've, probably inadvertently, introduced an animation delay.

Changing:

```
 -webkit-animation: anime1 .6s .1s ease-in forwards;
```

to:

```
 -webkit-animation: anime1 .6s ease-in forwards;
```

Seems to solve the problem for me.

Comment: Yes, this works. But often there is a need for a delay.

Comment: If you intended the delay, you can do that, by making a 'sequence' of animations. One for the first .1s keeping the div transparent, and the other for the next .6s fading it in. Use the percentages for instance. here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/KIKO_Software/3mkbb92e/